# Opening the file from directory according to the cell value, part of the file name with 2020 is skipped (not opening)

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory, cell

I have an excel file with the numbers in column C that represents the part of the filenames. The macro looks the cells in this column opens the directory where the current file is placed and looking for files with this part of the name as in cell. The code works perfectly with the eception of openning the file that contains number 2020. It skips only the file with number 2020. Is something have to do with the date from the system?

I am using following code:

```
Dim cell3 As Range
Dim FileName As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim Fpath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each cell3 In ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row)

eColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If eColumn >= 1 Then eColumn = eColumn + 1

Fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
CellName = cell3.Value

FileName = Dir(Fpath & "\*" & CellName & "*.xlsx")
    Select Case True
    Case Trim(cell3.Value) <> "" And Right(FileName, 12) Like "*" & CellName & "*"

                  Workbooks.Open FileName:=Fpath & FileName
                  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
                  Range("B1:B6").Select
                  Selection.Copy

                  Windows("PROBE.xlsm").Activate  
                  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(cell3.row, eColumn), Cells(cell3.row, eColumn)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                  Application.CutCopyMode = False
                  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                  wb.Close



                  End Select

Next cell3
```

Comment: What exactly is the filename that it is failing to match ? Also give an example of a filename that works.. Add a CASE ELSE statement to debug.print Right(FileName, 12)

Comment: It is failing to match file with name 2020 in directory, the other 40 files like 2320, 2110,06C1... the code is opening and pasting data perfectly. Just file 2020 skips.

Comment: So the non matching filename is just 2020.xlsx ? not .xls or .xlsm. Not letter O instead of zero 0.

Comment: No, it is .xlsx .Sorry, I've forgot to say my file name is something like this 03_2020_JK_DPS_2020.xlsx, 03_2020_JK_DPS_2170.xlsx and so on. And in the cell its only the part of the name 2020, 2170 and so on. The cell is not formated as Date.

Comment: when the cellname is 2020 dir *2020*.xlsx will return the dps_2170.xlsx filename which will fail the right(filename,12) match.

Comment: for other files it doesnt fail, because it is looking in the cell with number then searching directory with the file matching if in the file name exists for example 2170, and the code is searching and matching only the part of name given in the cell before, though it is 12 places from left, the other part of the file is ignored and then opens correctly the file. It is working for other 47 cells, my problem is that is not working only with cell where is the number 2020.

Comment: The dir star2020star will match 03_2020_Jk_DPS_2017.xlsx because of the 2020 in the filename. It returns the first file found that passes the filter star2020star.xlsx. That filename does not then pass the Like test. Maybe your filter should only contain one star before cell name. For all the other files the 2020 at the start makes no difference

Comment: Thank you for your advice, you are right. I found the solution, I removed wildecard * from FileName in ".xlsx" and now it takes file from directory. It was a contradictory filtering between FileName ......."*xlsx" and Like "*" & CellName & "*"